# How to change default shell for Linux susbsystem for Windows

Tags: windows-10, bash, shell, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Linux subsystem for Windows 10.  It works fine, but I want to change the default shell environment for the subsystem.

I did `sudo apt-get install fish` and then `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`. But when I start `bash.exe` in Windows, it always starts the bash (I think it is predictable).

Does anyone know arguments to change this behavior?

Comment: When you start `bash.exe` you are obviously *explicitly* starting bash. I'm not familiar with the Linux subsystem in Windows 10, but I would expect there to be some way to start a "Linux" shell without explicitly starting one specific shell.

Comment: Did you tried an ugly edition of your bashrc or bashprofile to re-route interactive bash calls to fish? Adding a line like `isatty && exec fish` may worth the try when you are totally out of actual solutions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot change the default shell per se since the Linux subsystem is started via the bash.exe residing in the system directory.

You can, however, make a new shortcut like the one that already exists for bash and make it run the command

```
%systemroot%\system32\bash -c /usr/bin/fish
```

This way you will be running fish immediately.

Comment: I used `%systemroot%\system32\bash.exe ~ -c /bin/zsh` to make ZSH open in my home directory.

Comment: Alternatively, set the "Start in" field in the shortcut to `%userprofile%` to start the shell in your home directory.

Comment: @konqui This doesn’t break any other shell. It’s a new shortcut for starting it. Your bash will work just fine

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen there wasn‘t anything said about a new shortcuts - i corrected it now i can life with this answer.

Comment: While this was correct when written, it's now mostly wrong.  First, the `bash.exe` way of starting WSL is now deprecated.  When started with `wsl` (the replacement command), WSL will start with whatever shell is defined in `/etc/passwd` (the normal Linux method of selecting the user's shell).  See [@Mikhail's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1264333/1210833) for the correct way to do this in "modern" WSL.

Answer (score 26):

When this question was originally asked, `bash.exe` was used to start WSL.  However, this command is now listed as "deprecated" in the WSL documentation.  If attempting to start via the deprecated `bash.exe`, command, the shell will always be (naturally) Bash.  Other answers here (such as running a different shell via `~/.bashrc`) or running with `bash -c` can be used, but they are less efficient and no longer recommended.

The replacement command for starting WSL is now `wsl.exe`, and since the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, you can use the "normal" Linux `chsh` to set the default shell for your user.

For example, to set `zsh` as default shell:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Then exit your existing shell and run (or restart) `wsl.exe` from command prompt.

Note that this has the same effect as (but is safer than) editing `/etc/passwd` directly as in some of the other answers.

Answer (score 9):

Open bash, run `nano ~/.bashrc` and paste this in:

```
if [[ -t 1 && -x /usr/bin/zsh ]]; then
    exec /usr/bin/zsh
fi
```

Just change the shell to `fish` or whatever you want. The `-x` check is important if you ever re-install Bash -- you won't be able to open it after a fresh install because the `exec` command will fail and then Bash just closes.

If that happens, delete/rename your `.bashrc` file here:

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\lxss\home\<USERNAME>\.bashrc
```

The `-t` I *believe* checks if stdout is open. Not sure why that's important, I copied it from [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/258518/how-to-use-zsh-or-another-shell-in-windows-10/).

Comment: for `-t 1` see [What does \[ -t 1 \] check?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389652/72456)

Answer (score 2):

## To change the default shell for the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Open WSL, log in and type the following - after you entered the SUDO command it will request your password.

```
   sudo nano /etc/passwd
```

Scroll down the list and amend the line with your username - usually it's the last line in the list.  e.g.

```
   username:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/username:/bin/fish
```

Restart WSL after your edits, and you should be logging in with the shell of your choice.

As we're using Windows as the host operating system, we can also edit the **passwd** file by navigating to this location:

> %LocalAppData%\Packages[Linux Distribution]\LocalState\rootfs\etc\passwd

Use a quality text editor like Notepad++ as it's capable of keeping Linux line break formatting.

Restarting the WSL will enable the edits.

This was based on @vvasch's answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just edited /etc/passwd. Setting the default shell for my user to zsh. Works without problems.

```
vvasch:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/vvasch:/bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can run `fish` from within the PowerShell after executing that one:

```
New-Item 'C:\Windows\System32\fish.bat' -ItemType File -Value 'ubuntu.exe run fish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the passwd file and change your username shell line.

`sudo vi /etc/passwd`

> pase:x:1000:1000:pase:/home/pase:/bin/**bash**
>
> > pase:x:1000:1000:pase:/home/pase:/bin/**zsh**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1121274)

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to link WSL Fish Shell to Windows Terminal
by simply adding

```
"commandline": "wsl -e fish",
"startingDirectory": "."
```

into Ubuntu Section of your `settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use e.g. `zsh` as your shell, you can update `$HOME/.bashrc` to be the following. As others have noted, WSL Ubuntu is started via the `bash` command.

`$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
zsh
exit
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Just a heads-up that this is fairly wrong.  First, you are basing this on an old, outdated answer -- WSL is no longer started with `bash.exe`.  That's an officially deprecated command according to the docs, so expect it to be removed at some point in the future.  The documented way to start WSL now is via the `wsl.exe` command, which uses the "normal" Linux way of choosing the shell (see [@Mikhail's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1264333/1210833)).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - AskUbuntu? SuperUser... ;-)

Comment: @Greenonline Oops!  Jane - Welcome to Super User!  Not the first time I've done that, and I'm sure I'll do it again, but twice (that I know of) in a few hundred comments probably ain't bad ;-)