# Windows Linux Subsystem: How can I bypass the normal shell and use Terminator (Xming X Server installed)?

Tags: linux, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been playing with the Windows Linux Subsystem and having Ubuntu so quickly and readily available through Windows in a non-clunky way has been very impressive.

I've got most of it set up the way I like. I installed an X Window Server and even that works a charm. I installed the Terminator shell and that works perfectly when called from bash.

I wanted to change the installed shortcut so that it opens Terminator straight away, so I had a look at the shortcut and it has a target...

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~
```

I tried changing it to this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~ -c "terminator"
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve the task of opening straight into Terminator?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest WSL (Windows Fall Creators Update), then you could achieve that with `chsh`:

> Set zsh as default shell:
>
> `chsh -s /bin/zsh`
>
> then run (or restart) ubuntu.exe from command prompt.

See also here: [How to change default shell for Linux susbsystem for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1110882/how-to-change-default-shell-for-linux-susbsystem-for-windows?rq=1)

Comment: I don't think the OP is trying to run a different shell instead of Bash.  I'm guessing they want to run a graphical terminal system; googling for "Terminator shell" gets me https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html

Comment: You're right, my fault. :( Try the procedure with VcXsrv. This should also solve the copy&paste to Windows issue when using WSL. See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/892#issuecomment-275873108

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following Windows shortcut:

> C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "export DISPLAY=:0.0 && terminator"

I am using VcXsrv instead of Xming, but it shouldnt matter, as long as you use the correct export of your display